# How to add confirm in shell script in sftp mode

Tags: shell, ssh, sftp, sh

I have a shell script which is performing some renaming and archiving steps. I have added sftp commands to copy multiple files. But when i try to login to the remote machine thru putty it asks for confirmation like **Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?** . I need to enter yes. but since this is being done thru the script am not sure how to do it. below is the script i am using

```
cd <File Source Location>
sftp user1@remoteserver
sftp> cd <target location to be copied>
sftp> mput *.gz 

quit
```

how to i pass yes in the above code after  `sftp user1@remoteserver` is executed.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

`sftp` asks you for confirmation because it does not know the key of the host yet. Therefore you need to add it to you `known_hosts` file like this

```
ssh-keyscan -H remoteserver >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I recommend using `scp` command instead of `sftp` as it will do all you want in one step.

```
scp somewhere/*.gz user1@remoteserver:somewhere/else
```

---

If for some reason you don't want to do it. You may consider a very **insecure** command

```
sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@remoteserver
```

**By using the command above you are vulnerable to Man in the Middle attack, you've been warned.**

Comment: thanks @Grzegorz. I added the key in known_hosts. we have to use sftp to copy files so i how to enter the mget command coz when i execute the shell script it executes everything and comes down and wait for me to input the command. is there a way to bypass this so that the script will pass the mget command.

Comment: @Sriram Yes, the `scp` command does exactly what you want, it is not interactive unlike `sftp` so you can use it in scripts.