# Shell script for kubectl for uploading a file on sftp

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script for automating the kubectl commands of uploading a file on the SFTP server. I am using the below sequence of commands and want to shell script them:

```
winpty  kubectl --kubeconfig="C:\kubeconfig" -n namespace exec -it podname -- bash -c "sftp username"
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?: yes
Enter password: *******
cd foldername
put filename
```

I can shell script the first command then it will ask for a prompt yes/no?. Stuck there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add confirm in shell script in sftp mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420253/how-to-add-confirm-in-shell-script-in-sftp-mode)

Comment: `echo "yes" | ./the_script.sh`